# Matrix variable not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, matrix, sum

I know that this type of question has been already put, but none of the solutions helped me out.
I want to make the sum of a matrix's elements when a key is hit from the keyboard, but the program gives me the next errors:

```
main.cpp|6|error: 'j' was not declared in this scope|
main.cpp|13|error: 'a' was not declared in this scope|
main.cpp|19|error: 'a' was not declared in this scope|
```

My program is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[i][j],i,j,s=0,n;
    char x;
    cout<<"n=";
    cin>>n;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            cout<<"a["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]=";
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
    cout<<"Type:"<<x;
    if(x=='1')
    {
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
                s=s+a[i][j];
        cout<<s;
        cout<<"bla bla bla";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong? The variables were declared at the begining of the program. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You declared them in the wrong order: `int i,j,a[i][j],s=0,n;` VLA's aren't standard C++ BTW, and how you declared it is pretty useless.

Comment: That's not even a proper VLA.

Answer (score -1):

Two problems: The first is about your error, and that is that variables are declared/defined in the order you actually do it in the source.

For example:

```
int i, j;
```

In the line above the variable `i` is declared *before* the variable `j`.

The second problem is that you try to use the variables `i` and `j` before they are initialized. That means they will have an *indeterminate* value and will give you *undefined behavior* when you use them.

A third point is that C++ doesn't have [*variable-length arrays*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), which means you can't actually declare arrays using run-time variables (though some compilers add it as a non-portable extension).

To solve all the above problems you need to either use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (which is what I recommend), or allocate memory dynamically with `new[]`.

---

There's a potential fourth problem too, and that is because array indexes in C++ are zero-based. So if you have an array of `N` elements, valid indexes go from `0` to `N - 1` (inclusive). Your loops over the arrays goes from `1` to `N` which will mean that the last index might be out of bounds.

Comment: I put `int i,j,a[100][100],s=0,n;` and it solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Ionut Continue to read my answer, because it's *still* wrong. It won't cause compiler error, but should give you warnings. And if you don't get warnings then enable more warnings, because warnings from the compiler is just as important to fix as actual errors.

Answer (score -1):

As with Line 6, the error lies in the part `int a[i][j]` which I believe is allowed nowhere(not even in JavaScript or Java) and so the variable 'i' and 'j' could only be constants with their values defined prior to array declaration if your syntax has to be like that. You can either go for dynamic array declaration

```
 int **a=new int[i];
```

and then for each column of the required matrix, you can have

```
for(int z=;z<j;z++)
    a[z]=new int[j];
```

where 'i' and 'j' must again be not only **previously declared** but also defined in some manner, if you have **memory constraints**.

Or take enough space before hand and then proceed, which I personally do not prefer, such as

`int a[100001];`

The subsequent errors are relative and would be solved if this problem is dealt with.

Also you have a problem while looping through your matrix as you are going `OutOfBounds`(0 to n-1 and not 1 to n) which may not cause any problems during run time as such but may lead to improper data retrieval and manipulation through other lines of codes.